# Android: Got an error 404 when connecting on a valid url

Tags: android, http-status-code-404, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to connect on a valid URL using the following code, but I got a 404 Error...

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(ConnectivityHelper.CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(ConnectivityHelper.READ_TIMEOUT);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

When I call

```
urlConnection.getInputStream()
```

I got a crash, because the httpResponse code was 404

What I don't understand is that the url does exists: http://www.plongeurs.tv/xml/itunes.xml
I trace it using wget and I got

```
--2012-07-01 16:24:52--  http://www.plongeurs.tv/xml/itunes.xml
Résolution de www.plongeurs.tv (www.plongeurs.tv)... 94.23.134.238
Connexion vers www.plongeurs.tv (www.plongeurs.tv)|94.23.134.238|:80... connecté.
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse... 200 OK
```

How come I get a 404 error in my app ?
FYI this is the only url I found having this problem, after testing it with 1000+ rss feeds

Comment: Do you have the permission to hit internet? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> Just something to check :p

Comment: as stated in my post my code works fine with more than 1000 differents urls... See my answer below for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it, I just tried it specifying a user-agent and now it works !

connection.setRequestProperty ("User-agent", "mozilla");